# Sync'ing SQL Server with a Web Service (both managed by different vendors)

Tags: asp.net, sql, performance

I had an interesting solution that I did get solved, but I wanted to know if there was a better way to solve it.

I have a piece of software that represents our core business process. This software (Application "A") is also managed by company A. I have admin access to the SQL server for the web application, but I don't have access to the compiled source code.

I have a second piece of software is managed by company B. Application B has integration hooks represented as web services so other applications can integrate with it. Other than that I don't have any real access to Application. It may be possible to get SQL Server Admin access to Application B, but at this time I don't have it.

My question is what is the best way to link these two systems so the data is as "near real time" as possible. I developed a CLR Trigger embedded in the SQL Server for Application A, but as all of you know it killed the performance of the application. So I ended up making another table on the SQL server which on a simple trigger wrote the necessary data related to the transaction along with a status column. I then setup a scheduled exe which read the data from the table, and fed it into Application B. It also updated the status column accordingly so I didn't run into threading problems as this executable runs on a high tight frequency.

The gap with my current solution is about 5min when everything is and done. That may not seem bad, but our end users are expecting real time so my support staff is still getting calls as a result of this solution.

Anyone got a better solution? I'm all ears and hoping to learn a bit in the process.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to have a single application managing a given data resource. If other resources need access to the data, then providing API through Web or Windows services is the best way. This centralizes the interactions with the data and also makes managing updates to how the database works much easier by reducing duplicated code.